# How to set include background color in android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to set background color on an `include` tag in Android? This does not work:

```
 <include
 android:id="@+id/list_item_section_text"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 layout="@android:layout/preference_category"
 android:background="%MY_BACKGROUND%"/>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> You can not give a background color into  `include` tag.

**Why ?**

Its obvious , if you could able to give the background color to `include` tag then it would be all messed up with your `include` color and another color which might be applied to that `layout` which has already included .

However, you can also override all the layout parameters (any android:layout_* attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the  tag.
(quoting from [https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Includ](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include) )

Comment: sorry, couldn't understand the obvious. Can you please explain how the colors would mess up? The color on top should be visible "on top" and if the color on top has alpha value, it should be blended with the background color. No?

Comment: In simple word To avoid the conflict of include tag value and the value contained by include tag , you are not allowed to provide the bg color to include tag

Comment: Okay, but then why does `layout_width:match_parent` work? Shouldn't there be conflict also?

Comment: This seems like a made up reason, other tags like id, dimensions are overwritten

Comment: @BugsHappen please refer https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include

Answer (score 24):

If you are not "too-deep-view-tree-paranoia" type of guy, you can **wrap your `include` in `FrameLayout`**:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_item_section_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="%YOUR_BACKGROUND%">

        <include layout="@android:layout/preference_category"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT**: Of course, don't forget to remove `android:background` from your `preference_category.xml` layout first.

Comment: Brilliant Solution :)

Answer (score 1):

for me `android:background="@color/colorSecondary"` to `<include>` tag is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/list_item_section_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@android:layout/preference_category"/>
```

in preference category layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/preference_category"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@colors/white"/>
```

otherwise changes in RUNTIME

```
preference_category.setBackgroundResource(R.id.bckResource);
```